merge 2 json arrays using ansible or jq
So I have 2 json array files
one with some simple data (could be any number of servers):
    [
    {
    "playbook": "simplerun.yml",
    "server": "abc",
    "status": "success"
    },
    {
    "playbook": "simplerun.yml",
    "server": "def",
    "status": "success"
    }
    etc
    ]

and a master file (hundreds of thousands of servers) with enhanced data about the server (but is called Name)
    [
    {
    "name": "abc",
    "fqdn": "abc.com",
    "env": "UAT",
    "ip_address": "0.0.0.0",
    "owner": "John Doe"
    },
    {
    "name": "def",
    "fqdn": "def.com",
    "env": "PROD",
    "ip_address": "0.0.0.1",
    "owner": "Jane Doe"
    }
    etc
    ]

what I would like to have is
    [
    {
    "playbook": "simplerun.yml",
    "server": "abc",
    "status": "success",
    "fqdn": "abc.com",
    "env": "UAT",
    "ip_address": "0.0.0.0",
    "owner": "John Doe"
    },
    {
    "playbook": "simplerun.yml",
    "server": "def",
    "status": "success",
    "fqdn": "def.com",
    "env": "PROD",
    "ip_address": "0.0.0.1",
    "owner": "Jane Doe"
    }
    ]

I know it must be simple, but
Any help is greatly appreciated.
I have tried combine
     - name: set fact
       set_fact:
         key1: "server"
         key2: "name"
     
     - name: join data
       set_fact:
         joined_data: >- 
           {{ jsonfile1 | map ('combine',
              jsonfile2 |selectattr (key2,'eq', item[key1]|list|first|default ({}))
           }}
       loop: "{{ jsonfile1 }}"
       loop_control:
         loop_var: item

however that only produced the same values for all the entries in the simple data.

Read the files, for example
  names: "{{ lookup('file', 'names.yml') }}"
  pb_status: "{{ lookup('file', 'pb_status.yml') }}"

gives
  names:
  - env: UAT
    fqdn: abc.com
    ip_address: 0.0.0.0
    name: abc
    owner: John Doe
  - env: PROD
    fqdn: def.com
    ip_address: 0.0.0.1
    name: def
    owner: Jane Doe

  pb_status:
  - playbook: simplerun.yml
    server: abc
    status: success
  - playbook: simplerun.yml
    server: def
    status: success

There are more options:

Get the list of servers

  servers: "{{ pb_status | map(attribute='server') }}"

gives
  servers:
  - abc
  - def

Select names in the servers' list
  names_sel: "{{ names | selectattr('name', 'in', servers) }}"

gives the same items here in testing, but there are a lot more items in production
  names_sel:
  - env: UAT
    fqdn: abc.com
    ip_address: 0.0.0.0
    name: abc
    owner: John Doe
  - env: PROD
    fqdn: def.com
    ip_address: 0.0.0.1
    name: def
    owner: Jane Doe

Rename the key server to name and merge the lists
  target:
      - {after: name, before: server}
  result: "{{ pb_status | community.general.replace_keys(target=target) |
                community.general.lists_mergeby(names_sel, 'name') }}"

gives what you want
  result:
  - env: UAT
    fqdn: abc.com
    ip_address: 0.0.0.0
    name: abc
    owner: John Doe
    playbook: simplerun.yml
    status: success
  - env: PROD
    fqdn: def.com
    ip_address: 0.0.0.1
    name: def
    owner: Jane Doe
    playbook: simplerun.yml
    status: success



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    names: "{{ lookup('file', 'names.yml') }}"
    pb_status: "{{ lookup('file', 'pb_status.yml') }}"

    servers: "{{ pb_status | map(attribute='server') }}"
    names_sel: "{{ names | selectattr('name', 'in', servers) }}"
    target:
      - {after: name, before: server}
    result: "{{ pb_status | community.general.replace_keys(target=target) |
                community.general.lists_mergeby(names_sel, 'name') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: names
    - debug:
        var: pb_status
    - debug:
        var: servers
    - debug:
        var: names_sel
    - debug:
        var: result




Group the status items and create a dictionary if there might be more status items for the same server

  pb_status_group: "{{ pb_status | groupby('server') | community.general.dict }}"

gives
  pb_status_group:
    abc:
    - playbook: simplerun.yml
      server: abc
      status: success
    def:
    - playbook: simplerun.yml
      server: def
      status: success

Convert the list of names to a dictionary too. It is expected that the names are unique
  names_dict: "{{ dict(names | json_query('[].[name, @]')) }}"

gives
  names_dict:
    abc:
      env: UAT
      fqdn: abc.com
      ip_address: 0.0.0.0
      name: abc
      owner: John Doe
    def:
      env: PROD
      fqdn: def.com
      ip_address: 0.0.0.1
      name: def
      owner: Jane Doe

After you have converted the lists to dictionaries the search will be more efficient. Select names
  names_sel: "{{ pb_status_group | map('extract', names_dict) }}"

gives the same items here in testing, but there are a lot more items in production
  names_sel:
  - env: UAT
    fqdn: abc.com
    ip_address: 0.0.0.0
    name: abc
    owner: John Doe
  - env: PROD
    fqdn: def.com
    ip_address: 0.0.0.1
    name: def
    owner: Jane Doe

Convert the dictionary pb_status_group to a list and merge the lists by name
  result: "{{ pb_status_group | dict2items(key_name='name', value_name='status') |
              community.general.lists_mergeby(names_sel, 'name') }}"

gives what want
  result:
  - env: UAT
    fqdn: abc.com
    ip_address: 0.0.0.0
    name: abc
    owner: John Doe
    status:
    - playbook: simplerun.yml
      server: abc
      status: success
  - env: PROD
    fqdn: def.com
    ip_address: 0.0.0.1
    name: def
    owner: Jane Doe
    status:
    - playbook: simplerun.yml
      server: def
      status: success



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    names: "{{ lookup('file', 'names.yml') }}"
    pb_status: "{{ lookup('file', 'pb_status.yml') }}"

    pb_status_group: "{{ pb_status | groupby('server') | community.general.dict }}"
    names_dict: "{{ dict(names | json_query('[].[name, @]')) }}"
    names_sel: "{{ pb_status_group | map('extract', names_dict) }}"
    result: "{{ pb_status_group | dict2items(key_name='name', value_name='status') |
                community.general.lists_mergeby(names_sel, 'name') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: names
    - debug:
        var: pb_status
    - debug:
        var: pb_status_group
    - debug:
        var: names_dict
    - debug:
        var: names_sel
    - debug:
        var: result



As jq is tagged, you seem to be looking for a JOIN:
jq '[JOIN(input | INDEX(.name); .[]; .server; add)]' simple.json master.json

[
  {
    "playbook": "simplerun.yml",
    "server": "abc",
    "status": "success",
    "name": "abc",
    "fqdn": "abc.com",
    "env": "UAT",
    "ip_address": "0.0.0.0",
    "owner": "John Doe"
  },
  {
    "playbook": "simplerun.yml",
    "server": "def",
    "status": "success",
    "name": "def",
    "fqdn": "def.com",
    "env": "PROD",
    "ip_address": "0.0.0.1",
    "owner": "Jane Doe"
  }
]

Demo
If you want the name field removed from the output, replace add with add | del(.name).
